# listview with multiple_choice problem

Tags: android, listview

```
    SparseBooleanArray selectedItem=catogoryList.getCheckedItemPositions();
    for(int i=0;i<selectedItem.size();i++)
    {
        System.out.println("Array val:"+selectedItem.valueAt(i));
        if(selectedItem.valueAt(i))
        {
            if(temp.contains(list.get(position)))
            {}
            else
            temp.add(list.get(position));
        }
        else
        {
            temp.remove(list.get(position));
        }
    }
```

I use listview with multiple_choice (listview with checkbox) when i get items in listview that is checked with out scrolling i received correct values if i scroll the listview i don't get correct values. i found that  selectedItem.valueAt(i) i  get false  when i check the items while scrolling. i don't know why false value is returned instead of true value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How do you obtain your values? This process should be like this:

```
    SparseBooleanArray checked = getCheckedItemPositions();
    List<String> checkedResult = new ArrayList<String>();

    for (int i = 0; i < checked.size(); i++) {
        if (checked.valueAt(i)) {
            checkedResult.add(getAdapter().getItem(checked.keyAt(i)).toString());
        }
    }
    return checkedResult;
```